# apache Vhosts getting 404

Tags: apache, vhosts

My vhosts file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/me/Desktop/httpApps/mySite“
    ServerName dev.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/AFW-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/AFW-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

My hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 dev.example.com
```

When I go to dev.example.com though I just get a 404 error. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

When I remove the vhost and just have my server pointing at the root of my httpApps dir I can see the file list as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this line:

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/me/Desktop/httpApps/mySite“
```

The end quote somehow became an invalid quote character. I'm not sure where that came from. But I've replaced it and it now works as expected.